# Tengo una duda con los arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Como puedo hacer para recorrer con un bucle for y que me diga cuantas notas hay suspendidas en ese array, intenté este código pero no me sale ,si alguien me puede ayudar. El array en este caso sería suspendidos.

```
for( let i=0; i<suspendidos.length; i++ ) 
        
        if (notas[i] < 5) {
            
            console.log(notas.length[i];)
        }
```

Y cuando le doy a consultar me sale indefinido.

Comment: Comparte por favor una muestra de ese array

Comment: Claro que te sale undefined... el array es `suspendidos` o `notas`? Son dos cosas diferentes. Por otro lado, intentas imprimir `notas.length[i]`.. el atributo `.length` es un entero que indica la longitud, no es un array. Si tu array es notas imprime `notas[i]` simplemente, pero asegúrate de que estás usando el array correcto!

Comment: Además aquí `console.log(notas.length[i];)` tienes un error de sintaxis, ese punto y coma va por fuera del paréntesis

Answer (score 0):

primero utiliza el nombre correcto del arreglo,  luego para acceder a los valores del arreglo solo debes indicar la posición

```js
var notas = [4, 7, 2, 10, 1];
var contador = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
  if (notas[i] < 5) {
    contador++;
  }
}
console.log(contador);
```